# Getting odd format on Bootstrap datetimepicker when I specify dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datetimepicker. I need it to format the date as dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyy.

The [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format) says this:

> ## format
>
> String. Default: “mm/dd/yyyy”
>
> The date format, combination of d, dd, D, DD, m, mm, M, MM, yy, yyyy.
>
> - d, dd: Numeric date, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 5, 05.
> - D, DD: Abbreviated and full weekday names, respectively. Eg, Mon, Monday.
> - m, mm: Numeric month, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 7, 07.
> - M, MM: Abbreviated and full month names, respectively. Eg, Jan, January
> - yy, yyyy: 2- and 4-digit years, respectively. Eg, 12, 2012.

so I have changed this:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
```

to this:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

However, I am now getting weird input values. Instead of `01/05/2015`, I get `Fr/35/yyyy`. 
[image: screenshot]

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dd` doing what it said `DD` would do was a clue.

I'm not sure why this happened, since it seems to work for others, but I was able to solve it by using `DD/MM/YYYY` (*contrary* to what the documentation says).

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

gives this:

[image: fix]

and with the hours in:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'
});
```

[image: fix with time]

Comment: I had similar experience when date form field was set to  `initial=datetime.now()` Using datepicker to change date gave similar weird results eg 'Saturday/March/YYYY hh:03' with datepicker format set to `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'`. Removing `initial=datetime.now()` fixes that but still have to figure out how to get initial date set ..

Comment: Ah the weirdness comes from using datetimepicker on DateTimeField instead of DateField

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you were referencing the documentation for a different bootstrap datepicker. The version in your screenshots looks to be https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Eonasdan's Bootstrap DatetimePicker uses moment formats http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ and the correct documentation can be found at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I actually already had that documentation and was using the "linked picker" example from it. However, I couldn't find anything in it about how to change the format of the date, so I Googled and found the documentation linked in the question. I now see that there is a top menu as well as the side menu that I was frantically exploring, that completely passed me by the first time... sigh.